# Can't change the iOS14 widget background color

Tags: ios, widget, swiftui, background-color

I know I can change the views background colors in SwiftUI with this code:

```
.background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
```

But I can't do it for widget background color itself!

I use this code:

```
struct XWidget: Widget { // MARK: Widget is defined here
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(
            kind: "xWidget",
            provider: xProvider(),
            placeholder: Text("Loading...")) { entry in
            xWidgetEntryView(entry: entry).background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground)) // <= here
        }.supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }
}
```

But the result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to specify full frame, as on below demo

[image: demo]

```
StaticConfiguration(
    kind: "xWidget",
    provider: xProvider(),
    placeholder: Text("Loading...")) { entry in
    xWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)    // << here !!
       .background(Color.green)
}.supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. But how can I define to colors for day and dark mode? Can you also tell me how I can set an image instead of color?

Comment: I use a combination of this and the WidgetBackround color assets, after defining the WIdgetBackground color for light and black, use Color("WidgetBackground") instead of Color.green in the code above.

Answer (score 20):

*For those who are trying to change the widget background that supports both **dark** and **light** modes.*

## Change widget background color (supports dark mode)

1. Go to `Assets.xcassets` in your **Widget Extension**
2. There should be a **Color Set** already with name `"WidgetBackground"`
3. If it's missing, then create a new **Color Set** and name it as `"WidgetBackground"`
4. Go to the **Attribute Inspector** and make sure the **Appearances** is set to `"Any, Dark"`

[image]

5. Go to your **Widget Extension**'s **Build Settings** and search for the **Asset Catalog Compiler - Options**
6. Make sure the Widget Background Color Name is set to the name of the Color Set "WidgetBackground"

[image]

7. Go to your widget view and set its background color `.background(Color("WidgetBackground"))`

```swift
public var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: MyCustomTimeline()) { entry in
        MyCustomWidgetView(entry: entry)
            .background(Color("WidgetBackground"))
    }
}
```

8. Compile and Run on device (or Simulator) and check the color updates to the current appearance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also set a color within your widget view using a ZStack like so:

```
var body: some View {
        
       VStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Link(destination: Deeplink.image.url!) {
                    Image("exampleImage")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .padding(.vertical, 3)
                }
            }
            Text("Example text")
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seem the "most right". It's simple and logical. I'd perhaps swap the Z and V stacks, though, like: `ZStack { Color.black.ignoresSafeArea() VStack { //widget content goes here } }`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the background color of your widget, you should modify your Assets.xcassets.

The Assets.xcassets in the Widget target has a Color Set named "WidgetBackground".

Changing the "WidgetBackground" color not only changes the background color of your widget, but also the background color of the add button of the widget that appears in the Widget Library.

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. It changed the color of the button but the color of the widget is still same. Can you also show how to set 2 color for night and day?

Comment: That's in the attributes inspector to the right; you can select the appearance (any, light, dark)

Comment: doesnt work... how do you set the canvas color?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. For some reason the build fails with `Failed to find newest available Simulator runtime` if set to anything else than "None"

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 17+, [containerBackground(_:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/containerbackground(_:for:)) is available.

```swift
public var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: MyCustomTimeline()) { entry in
        MyCustomWidgetView(entry: entry)
            .containerBackground(.red.tertiary, for: .widget)
    }
}
```